# How to return to position using jQuery animate

Tags: jquery

I have the following code, and if I only use the first if statement it works as intended. The addition of the else if statement makes the element not behave properly in either functions.

The goal is to animate it to a certain position when the window is resized below a certain point. If the window is resized larger it is supposed to return to the starting position.

```
var logoPosition = $('.akc-logo').position();
console.log(logoPosition);

$(window).resize(function display(){
   console.log($(window).width());
      if($(window).width()<991){
         $('.akc-logo').animate({left: '20em'}, 1000);
      }else if($(window).width()>991){
         $('.akc-logo').animate({top: logoPosition.top, left: logoPosition.left}, 1000);
      }
});
```

Comment: What specifically goes wrong? Is it possible to create a working example, either as a [stack snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @showdev I cant send a working example but what occurs is when the window is resized to under 991px and I have both if statements, the logo moves erratically down to the wrong position. If I don't have the second if statement it moves correctly to the intended position. My goal is to have it return to the original position when the window is resized larger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue might be related to the animation queue. Since resize events can fire at a high rate, many animations can become queued. Animations will be executed in the order they are queued and it might take a while before you see the animation that is appropriate for the current window size.

In my example, I've added jQuery's [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) so that the current animation is cancelled before another one is started.

(Note: Use the "Full Page" link to test window resizing.)

```js
var logoPosition = $('.akc-logo').position(),
  threshold = 500;

$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < threshold) {
    $('.akc-logo').stop().animate({
      left: '20em'
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    $('.akc-logo').stop().animate({
      top: logoPosition.top,
      left: logoPosition.left
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
div.akc-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="akc-logo"></div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgk3kybc/)

I also recommend [throttling or debouncing your resize handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize#Example).

Check out:
[Paul Irish's Debounced Resize() jQuery Plugin](http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/)
[David Walsh's JavaScript Debounce Function](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)
[Ben Alman's throttle/debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/)

---

### Edit:

A more light-weight solution would be to handle the animation with CSS and a media query. But I suppose the efficacy of this solution depends on your specific context.

```css
.akc-logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 20em;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-transition: left 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: left 1s ease-in-out;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .akc-logo {
    left: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="akc-logo"></div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgk3kybc/1/)